# Submit MySQL query from a textbox?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a database created with some users in it on my website and would like to have a form on my website with a textbox that allows me to submit a full SQL query against my DB.

Is this possible when using PHP? I see it is possible in ASP.net but I am a bit unfamiliar with that language.

Example:

On my page, run_sql.php, I would like a textbox with a submit button.

In the textbox I would like to be able to run a command, such as

```
INSERT INTO `userdata`(`UserID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email`, `PF_Username`, `PF_Password`, `Endpoint`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7])
```

and have that write the declared values into my table.

sql.php code just for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Run SQL - TEST</title>
  </head>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="images/api_rat.png">
        </td>
        <td>
          <h1>TEST</h1>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<body>
    <form action="sql.php" method="GET">
        <textarea name="comments" cols="25" rows="5">Enter your SQL query here...</textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Run Query on LIVE DB" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: Possible?  Sure.  Dangerous?  Extremely.

Comment: It strikes me as a great way to lose all your data.

Comment: It's definitely doable... that's basically what `phpmyadmin` does.

Comment: As @diggersworld said, you should probably use phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Reminds me of one of Murphy Laws. "If something can go wrong, it will go wrong, and it will go wrong in a manner that is most destructive"

Comment: I do this all the time in Java apps (not php but the same concept). But definitely NOT on screens accessible to the user. What I've done a few times is make a stand-alone app for ad hoc queries where I can type in a db connection string or have a drop-down of the databases I may want to query. Then make this app only accessible inside the building or over the VPN or otherwise put tight controls on it.

Comment: All the answers so far are using the [old deprecated mysql API](http://php.net/mysql_query). Using one of the newer APIs (PDO or mysqli) would, among other things, allow [multiple SQL statements per query](http://php.net/mysqli_multi_query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, make a connect, and then do a mysql_query($_GET['comments']);

But you know, that if this script is accessable from the net, you have a REALLY REALLY BIG PROBLEM? :-)

Comment: Thanks for the info Fabian. But yes, I am aware of the potential security issue. I just haven't figured out what I am gonna do about that yet. Prlly password protect my directory? Again, not sure yet. This site/database is more of a proof of concept so not mission critical if someone messes with it.

Comment: then be sure, the database user which is used only has rights on the one database :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but it's a *really* bad idea. What if someone types in `DROP TABLE myreallyimportanttable`?

Still, if you want to do it, just capture the text box input as a string, and feed it to a mysql connection;

```
$sql = $_GET['comments'])
$dbconn = @mysql_pconnect("$dbhost:$dbport", $dbuser, $dbpassword);
return @mysql_query ($sql, $dbconn);
```

Have fun with your SQL injection attacks!

Comment: Well... to be pedantic, it's not really a SQL injection attack when the design is to allow execution of user-supplied SQL.

Comment: @josh3736 nice comment, very logical :) +1

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$sql = $_GET["comments"];
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
//if it works show this
}else{
//if it doesnt work show this
}
?>
```

if it doesnt work tell me.